# when is insertion sort faster than merge sort?

Tags: runtime, mergesort, insertion-sort

For a homework problem, I was told that insertion sort runs at 8n^2 and that merge sort runs at 64(n(lg n)). As part of the solution I was given, it said that insertion sort was faster than merge sort as long as n <= 43, but the teacher's answer doesn't really explain why or how he arrived at 43. Can anyone explain this? I'm not that great with figuring out run times so I'm trying to get a better understanding. And yes, I tried asking the teacher, but I was still confused. Any help would be great! thank you!

Comment: Please ask questions directly. Avoid adding stories.

Comment: okay, can do. why is n <= 43?

Answer (score 7):

It came from this (algebraic) line of reasoning

```
steps_in_insertion_sort <= steps_in_merge_sort
8n^2 <= 64n lg n
n^2 <= 8n lg n
n <= 8 lg n
```

Then 43 works by trial and error, or by solving for the zero of the equation n - 8 lg n = 0.

For hacking by trial and error, note:

```
$ python
>>> 8 * log(43)/log(2)
43.41011803761678
```

Because "lg"  means log-base-two.

(Aside: calculations like this do not really translate to any real-world indication that one algorithm will beat another.  Seriously, exactly 43?)

Comment: Where `8n^2 <= 64n lg n` comes from?

Comment: Those values came from question. I guess the 8 and 64 were some arbitrary values assigned to the nebulous constants we see in doing asymptotic analysis, just to make the problem have some concrete values.

Comment: I meant how the math worked out in this case: `n^2 <= 8n lg n`? But `n^2 >= n lg n`

Comment: For certain values of n, it will be `<=` and for other values of n it will be `>=`. The thing to do is to find the cutoff.

Answer (score 2):

This is the second exercise question in Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition by Cormen. 
The solution to this equation is not so straight forward for a newcomer to algorithms:

Insertion
sort
beats
merge
sort
when
8n^2
<
64n
lg
n
,
n
<
8
lg
n
,
2^
n/8
<
n
.
This
is
true
for
2
<=
n
<=
43
(found
by
using
a
calculator).
Therefore, we can rewrite
merge
sort
to
use
insertion
sort
for
input
of
size
43
or
less
in
order
to
improve
the
running
time.